# SQL - Optimize nested queries in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

hope to pick on the wisdom of the folks here. (current approach at the bottom)

Please see the SQL Fiddle Link below.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4a818/1

```
create table paymentmethod (
  methodtype varchar(6) not null,
  methodname varchar(6) not null
);

insert into paymentmethod values
  ('cc', 'mstr'),
  ('cc', 'visa'),
  ('cc', 'amex')
;

create table chargepolicy (
  accountname varchar(6) not null,
  methodtype varchar(6) not null,
  methodname varchar(6) not null,
  chargerate float not null
);

insert into chargepolicy values
  ('acct1','cc', 'mstr', 0.02),
  ('acct1','cc', 'visa', 0.02),
  ('acct1','cc', 'amex', 0.025),
  ('acct2','cc', 'all', 0.015),
  ('acct3','cc', 'amex', 0.03),
  ('acct3','cc', 'all', 0.02),
  ('acct4','cc', 'visa', 0.0),
  ('acct4','cc', 'all', 0.025)
 ;


select * from chargepolicy, paymentmethod
where chargepolicy.methodtype = paymentmethod.methodtype
and (chargepolicy.methodname = paymentmethod.methodname
     or chargepolicy.methodname = 'all')
order by 1,2,3;
```

So, this a hypothetical case (obviously). I have payment methods like Visa,MasterCard, Amex and then charge rates for each of these methods. The charge rates will vary base on the account. These accounts to method & rate mapping is defined in another table.

Now then, when I have charge rates defined for each method, things work fine (e.g. acct1 and acct2). Things get insteresting - and this is where I need help - when we come to acct3 and acct4. In acct3, I am saying that for Amex the charge should be 3% and for everything else (all - Amex) it should be 2%. Similarly, in acct4, I want charge for Visa to be 0% and for everything else to be 2.5%.

The way current SQL is written, I am getting two values for acct3.amex and acct4.visa.

How can I simplify that. It must be a straight forward thing but I don't believe I am looking at it right.

This is what I have come up with:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/36a1c/6

```
select * 
from 
  chargepolicy, 
  paymentmethod
where 
  chargepolicy.methodtype = paymentmethod.methodtype
  and (chargepolicy.methodname = paymentmethod.methodname
     or (chargepolicy.methodname = 'all'
    and paymentmethod.methodname not in (
    select methodname from chargepolicy cp2 where cp2.accountname = chargepolicy.accountname
      and cp2.methodname !='all')
    ))
order by 1,2,3;
```

But since my actual use case has a lot of additional options to be mapped (e.g. Country, Product, Currency etc), I am not sure if my current approach is scalable - too many nested queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be like this, its much simpler to follow i think.

```
select 
ac.accountname,
pm.methodtype,
pm.methodname,
coalesce(cp1.chargerate,cp2.chargerate) as chargerate
from 
  paymentmethod as pm
  join (select distinct accountname from chargepolicy) as ac on 1=1
  left join chargepolicy as cp1 on pm.methodname=cp1.methodname and ac.accountname=cp1.accountname 
  left join chargepolicy as cp2 on cp2.methodname='all' and ac.accountname=cp2.accountname 
order by 1,2,3;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/36a1c/11

Comment: Thanks Jon. I love the how you chose to pick a different table as base. Pretty neat !

Comment: No problem - would you mind making an edit & putting your sqlfiddle SQL inside your question (as embedded code) - as many won't take that sqlfiddle link, it will make more sense for others to read & also will come up in searches.

Comment: Jon, thanks. I will play with the approach. The proposed solution will break if there are multiple method name for an account. 
Also, I have lot of dimensions than just MethodName and MethodType. 

Appreciate the help regardless.